# How can a civil judge override the jury's award?

Tags: constitutional-law, civil-law, jury, judge

In a civil case in which the jury decides an award for the plaintiff, under what circumstances and with what limits can a judge reduce this award?

Does this implicate either the 6th or 7th Amendments?

Answer (score 2):

Judicial review of the size of punitive damages is a "well-established common-law protection against arbitrary and inaccurate adjudication" and without it, the defendant is deprived of Due Process guaranteed by the Fourteenth Amendment. [Honda Motor Co. v. Oberg 512 U.S. 415 (1994)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/512/415/case.html).

While the Seventh Amendment protects your right to a jury trial in civil matters, the Constitution also protects the defendant against excessive awards under the Fourteenth Amendment's Due Process Clause.

Answer (score 1):

If the judge believes the award is too high or too low, the judge can use [additur](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Additur) or [remittitur](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/remittitur) to reduce the damages.

These are essentially offers to both parties to agree to the change in damages. If both parties do not agree, the court can order a new trial.

Answer (score -1):

A party can make a motion for a judgment notwithstanding the verdict (JNOV) if they've previously moved for a judgment as a matter of law.  A JNOV can result in a trial judge overturning a jury's verdict.  In addition, a jury's verdict can be overturned on appeal for a variety of reasons.